# Bitmask 0b1 parsing back to int

Tags: java, bitmask

Is there a way in **Java SDK 1.8** to parse a String like `"0b1"` back to its integer value ?

I tried with `Integer.parseInt` but it fails.

Same question with this String `"0b1111_1101"` ?

Maybe there's something in Eclipse.JDT to eval this as a java expression.

**EDIT:**

In order to give a little bit more context about what I'm trying to achieve:
It's related to a modification of Sharpen (converter of Java code to C#) in order to convert a bit mask string declaration in a valid C# int declaration (this bit mask notation is still not managed by C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [wero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215527/wero) solution and my own solution and finally I kept mine because while not being too complex, it's faster. However, as I'm not that good in Java, maybe there is still room for improvement.

**[wero solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215527/wero):**

```
public static String simplerRewriteBitMask(String token) {
    String input = "0b1111_1111";
    input = input.replace("0b", "");
    input = input.replace("_", "");
    return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(input, 2));
}
```

**my solution (with the improvements of [JoopEggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen))**

```
private static String rewriteBitMask(String token) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < token.length(); ++i) {
        char character = token.charAt(i);
        if (character != '_') {
            int bit = Character.digit(character, 2);
            result = result << 1;
            result |= bit;
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because a solution without replace is a good idea, though improvements always possible. Newer java: `Integer.parseUnsignedInt` helps for "unsigned" values above Integer.MAX_VALUE. `<<` and `|` would be more fitting, as would be `charAt` and `Character.digit`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to strip of the prefix `"0b"`, replace any `"_"` with `""`, and then use `Integer.parseInt(n, 2)` to get the `int` value.